# Python scripts enabled to run w/out the CLI do not take command line arguments

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, argparse

In windows 7, if a python (2.7.10) script has been associated with the Python interpreter and the extension has been registered in the PATHEXT (windows) list, then when you kick off a script, one can simply type:

```
MyPythonScript
```

instead of the traditional:

```
python MyPythonScript.py
```

Which is great - but it **no longer (appears) to take command line arguments**. For example, consider the two below examples of a script that takes command line arguments. First the traditional way:

```
>>>> python echo_input.py --help

usage: echo_input.py [-h] [-s SIMPLE_VALUE] [-c] [-t] [-f] [-a COLLECTION]
                     [-A] [-B] [--version]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -s SIMPLE_VALUE  Store a simple value
  -c               Store a constant value
  -t               Set a switch to true
  -f               Set a switch to false
  -a COLLECTION    Add repeated values to a list
  -A               Add different values to list
  -B               Add different values to list
  --version        show program's version number and exit
```

works just fine, but if it is invoked the **alternative** way:

```
echo_input --help

simple_value     = None
constant_value   = None
boolean_switch   = False
collection       = []
const_collection = []
```

It appears to no longer recognizes the command line arguments. FYI: The above script (by default) prints out those 5 lines if the it is run w/out any parameters as shown below for contrast:

```
>python echo_input.py

simple_value     = None
constant_value   = None
boolean_switch   = False
collection       = []
const_collection = []
```

So it appears as though it has **lost it's ability to take command line arguments** such as a simple flag for help.

I'm stuck for both an answer to this and a work around and would greatly appreciate any suggestions or experience.

Thank you in advance for your time ... :-)

Sources of inspiration:

**[Registering Python Scripts to run on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/4284/can-i-register-python-scripts-to-execute-on-windows):**

[Python FAQ2:](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable)

Comment: It's not an argparse issue.  It's a question of what is in `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work (thanks @eryksun for suggested fixes -- I don't have a Windows machine any more)?

```
C:\>ftype Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
C:\>assoc .py=Python.File
```

This adds/modifies the ProgId in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes`. Depending on the current configuration, you may also have to select this ProgId (`Python.File`) in Explorer's "open with" dialog.